# Dynamic Array Overwriting

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to array and I have a decrypt function and sql query. Process is I query in the database and return the $get in an array like so:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
 array (size=3)
   'Username' => string 'joenefloresca' (length=13)
   'MiddleName' => string 'Estero' (length=6)
   'Email' => string 'joenefloresca@gmail.com' (length=23)
```

What I want is to use my decrpyt function (data is encrypted, above is just an example). When I decrypt
it I want it to overwrite $get array with the decrypted values. I can do it this way,

```
foreach( $get as $key => $result )
{    
 $get[$key]['Username'] = $decr->decrypt($result['Username']);
 $get[$key]['MiddleName'] = $decr->decrypt($result['MiddleName']);
 $get[$key]['Email'] = $decr->decrypt($result['Email']);
}
```

But I can do that if my Fields like Username,MiddleName,Email is fixed in the sql query, what if
it is dynamic? Fields in the query is defined by the user, ex. What if Username is the only field? or Username and Email only? How can I overwrite the array with the decrypted one with the selected Field only?

Thanks.

Comment: Use second loop `foreach($result as $field => $value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just nest another loop inside if you do not want to explicitly set the index you want:

```
foreach($get as $key => $result) {
    foreach($result as $k => $val) { // will loop for each piece/copy of `$result`
        $get[$key][$k] = $decr->decrypt($val);
    }
}
```